# No data available in a table in server-side processing mode

Tags: javascript, datatables, laravel-5.1

I want to show my record data into table enhanced by jQuery DataTables plugin using server-side processing mode. I followed the docs [Datatables Server side](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) but in my table I can't show the record data.

Here's my Ajax response:

```js
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 4,
    "recordsFiltered": 4,
    "data": [
        [
            27,
            "Brokoli Segar",
            "25000"
        ],
        [
            28,
            "Tomat Super",
            "2000"
        ],
        [
            29,
            "Oreo Roll",
            "9400"
        ],
        [
            30,
            "Close Up Toothpaste Fire Freeze",
            "7000"
        ]
    ],
    "queries": [
        {
            "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as row_count from `product` where `product`.`deleted_at` is null) count_row_table",
            "bindings": [],
            "time": 0.79
        },
        {
            "query": "select `id`, `name`, `price` from `product` where `product`.`deleted_at` is null",
            "bindings": [],
            "time": 0.68
        }
    ],
    "input": []
}
```

My HTML table:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tabelStokBarang">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nama Barang</th>
                <th>Harga Barang</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
$('#tabelStokBarang').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('admin.product.stock.getAll') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'price', name: 'price' }
        ]
    });
```

My result in table is still "No data available". I don't know what I've missed.

Comment: Hi, How did you solve this problem. I am also fetching the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `columns` to match your data because you're returning rows as arrays but with `columns` property expecting rows to be objects with properties `id`, `name` and `price`. See the code below:

```
$('#tabelStokBarang').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('admin.product.stock.getAll') !!}'
});
```

Another potential problem is that your `draw` parameter is `0`. Your script should return `draw` parameter with the same value of the `draw` parameter in the request. I believe it starts at `1` and then increments with every request.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data):

> `draw`
>
> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the `draw` parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is **strongly recommended for security reasons** that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the `draw` parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: i deleted columns, but nothing change.

Comment: @Ghali, you may need to correct the problem with `draw` parameter, it should match the `draw` parameter value in the request.

Comment: draw parameter must return "1"? how? my result always return "0"

Comment: @Ghali, it must match the `draw` parameter value in the request, see the quote or the manual I referenced in my answer.